# How to view the shadowmap

Tags: three.js, webgl

I would like to be able to view the generated shadow maps from all the scene light sources (spot-light or directional-light) on a separate canvas element.

Is there a way to achieve this with three.js? I would like some pointers.

Comment: On second canvas, setup renderer, add quad with simple fragment shader that samples texture (your depth map) and render it with orthographic camera.

Generally, depth map is being rendered into previously setup renderbuffer, and with the quad's material you send sampler2D uniform that corresponds to renderbuffer's color attachment.

I haven't put answer because I'm not sure if this is what you need.

Comment: Yes this is what I want but I can't find any examples that do something similar. Also if the scene has 10 lights for example, wouldn't it be expensive to setup 10 renderers and 10 different scenes?

Comment: Directional light should be only one, so only one map.
For spotlights, if there are multiple, don't generate shadow maps but simulate shadows or lighten area with some projective texturing or similar, something that wouldn't require to render N depth maps if there are N lights. If you real need it you should consider maybe deferred rendering, you can find few examples at threejs.org, but it's still in-progress.

Comment: I really did not ask how to simulate n-spot-light shadowmaps. Just how to display them. And by the way a scene can have n directional lights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to view the shadowmap from one light (spot or directional) you can do the following:

```
// render scene as you normally would.
// after this call the shadowmp has been generated
renderer.render (scene, camera);

// render a scene of one quad to see the shadowmap on your canvas
quadMaterial.uniforms.map.value = light.shadowmap;
renderer.render (quadScene, quadCamera);
```

In a previous stage you need to set up the quadCamera

```
// set up an orthographic camera
quadCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera (textureWidth / - 2, textureHeight / 2, textureWidth / 2, textureHeight / - 2, -1000, 1000);
quadCamera.position.z = 100;
```

and the quadScene

```
var quadScene = new THREE.Scene ();

quadMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial ({

        uniforms:
        {
            map: { type: "t", value: null },
        },

        vertexShader:
        [
            "varying vec2 vUv;",

            "void main ()",
            "{",
                "vUv = vec2 (uv.x, 1.0 - uv.y);",
                "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4 (position, 1.0);",
            "}"
        ].join("\n"),

        fragmentShader:
        [
            "uniform sampler2D map;",
            "varying vec2 vUv;",

            "float unpack_depth (const in vec4 rgba_depth)",
            "{",
                "const vec4 bit_shift = vec4 (1.0 / (256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0), 1.0 / (256.0 * 256.0), 1.0 / 256.0, 1.0);",
                "float depth = dot (rgba_depth, bit_shift);",

                "return depth;",
            "}",

            "void main ()",
            "{",
                "vec4 rgbaDepth = texture2D (map, vUv);",
                "float fDepth = unpack_depth (rgbaDepth);",

                "gl_FragColor = vec4 (vec3 (fDepth), 1.0);",
            "}"
        ].join("\n"),

        blending: THREE.NoBlending,
        depthTest: false,
        depthWrite: false,
    });

quadScene.add (new THREE.Mesh (
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry (textureWidth, textureHeight), quadMaterial));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_complex.html
and
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_multiple_canvases_grid.html

There should be THREE.MeshDepthMaterial, if not create you own depth-like THREE.ShaderMaterial.

Comment: MeshDepthMaterial is used to apply the depth info onto a mesh. It is a ShaderMaterial that I need to use just dont know how. I found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DW9q4/43/ but it only displays black.